# Create historical S&P 500 constituents dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a DataFrame with S&P 500 companies for each day during the last 20 years. I have the data of entries and exists that has records on each company´s entry date and exist date (if its the case). It goes as follows (many more rows):

```
    Action    Company            Code         Date
0   Added    FactSet Res         FDS.N      2021-12-20
1   Removed  HanesBrands         HBI.N      2021-12-20
2   Removed  Leggett & Platt     LEG.N      2021-12-20
3   Added    Signature Bank      SBNY.OQ    2021-12-20
4   Added    Solaredge Tech      SEDG.OQ    2021-12-20
5   Added    HanesBrands         HBI.N      2015-03-23
6   Added    Leggett & Platt     LEG.N      1999-10-18
```

In another dataframe I have each trading date as the index and as the columns every unique company Code. It looks like this (many more columns):

```
   Dates   FDS.N   HBI.N   LEG.N  SBNY.OQ  SEDG.OQ      
1999-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2000-01-03  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2000-01-04  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2000-01-05  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2000-01-06  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-12-27  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-28  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-29  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-30  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

What I am trying to do is populate the second DataFrame with the name of each company if at each index date the company was part of the index or not. It would be something like this (this is just an example):

```
   Dates   FDS.N   HBI.N   LEG.N  SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ     
1999-12-31  NaN     NaN    LEG.N     NaN       NaN
2000-01-03  NaN     NaN    LEG.N     NaN       NaN
2000-01-04  NaN     NaN    LEG.N     NaN       NaN
2000-01-05  NaN     NaN    LEG.N     NaN       NaN
2000-01-06  NaN     NaN    LEG.N     NaN       NaN
...         ...     ...     ...     ...        ...
2021-12-27  FDS.N   NaN     NaN    SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ
2021-12-28  FDS.N   NaN     NaN    SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ
2021-12-29  FDS.N   NaN     NaN    SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ
2021-12-30  FDS.N   NaN     NaN    SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ
2021-12-31  FDS.N   NaN     NaN    SBNY.OQ   SEDG.OQ
```

I really can´t figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Extract by issue in the data frame of listing date and delisting date, and if there are two rows, the first row is listed and the second row is delisted because listing and delisting exist, and the date range is obtained as the last day of the designation since there is only the listing date in the case of one row. Finally, update the data from the S&P with the index of the desired trading date.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import yfinance as yf

sp500_idx = yf.download("^GSPC", periods=max)
new_index = sp500_idx.loc['1999-12-31':'2021-12-31',].index

data = '''
    Action    Company            Code         Date
0   Added    "FactSet Res"         FDS.N      2021-12-20
1   Removed  "HanesBrands"         HBI.N      2021-12-20
2   Removed  "Leggett & Platt"     LEG.N      2021-12-20
3   Added    "Signature Bank"      SBNY.OQ    2021-12-20
4   Added    "Solaredge Tech"      SEDG.OQ    2021-12-20
5   Added    "HanesBrands"         HBI.N      2015-03-23
6   Added    "Leggett & Platt"     LEG.N      1999-10-18
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
# start = '1999-12-31'
end = '2021-12-31'
for c in df['Code'].unique():
    dfc = df.query('Code == @c')
    dfc = dfc.sort_values('Date', ascending=True).reset_index()
    if len(dfc) == 2:
        drange = pd.date_range(dfc.loc[0,'Date'], dfc.loc[1,'Date'])
    else:
        drange = pd.date_range(dfc.loc[0,'Date'], end)
    s = pd.Series(c, index=drange, name=c)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, s],axis=1)


    FDS.N   HBI.N   LEG.N   SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
Date                    
1999-12-31  NaN     NaN     LEG.N   NaN     NaN
2000-01-03  NaN     NaN     LEG.N   NaN     NaN
2000-01-04  NaN     NaN     LEG.N   NaN     NaN
2000-01-05  NaN     NaN     LEG.N   NaN     NaN
2000-01-06  NaN     NaN     LEG.N   NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-12-27  FDS.N   NaN     NaN     SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
2021-12-28  FDS.N   NaN     NaN     SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
2021-12-29  FDS.N   NaN     NaN     SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
2021-12-30  FDS.N   NaN     NaN     SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
2021-12-31  FDS.N   NaN     NaN     SBNY.OQ     SEDG.OQ
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Not working, it correctly considers delistings dates but not listing dates. For example, HBI.N was added on 2015-03-23 but with this code it starts the very first date (1999-12-31).

Comment: HBI.N not LEG.N? And the data in question does not say it was listed on 2015-03-23. I need the listing and delisting dates in the data you provide.

Comment: I have edited the listing and delisting dates for those stocks. What I posted before were some non-real examples.

Comment: The question was updated and a discontinuance date was added, so the logic was changed and the answer was updated.